# What is the correct method of logout in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [proper way to logout from a session in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512507/proper-way-to-logout-from-a-session-in-php)

I am using session_destroy for logout.Bt it destroys all the session so i found unset a particular session.What is the correct way?
session_destroy() or unset(particularsession) for logout?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to destroy your session at the end of the php code using session_destroy()

Comment: Its the best way of destroying all sessions

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application, If you want to destroy all php sessions use `session_destroy()`. If you want to destroy a particular session use `unset($_SESSION['name_here'])`.

Of course there are times when you may not want to destroy all session variables as they are not only used for logins and logouts. For that pupose you'll use `` unset($_SESSION['name_here`]) ``.

Answer (score 0):

I use this piece of code to log somebody out:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION);
    header('Location: '.ROOT_HREF.');
    die();
?>
```