# Logout is not working

Tags: php, session, logout

I have a logout button which doesn't seem to work well. After clicking on it I can still see the "Welcome username" and the logout button is still there as in the picture below. Please let me know what's missing on my `logout.php`.

May I also ask how I could redirect the user back to the orginal page after clicking logout ? I try to use `"header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);"` but it doesn't work ?

[image]
Index.php

```
<?php
ini_set("session.save_path", "sessionData");
session_start();
?>

 <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['uName'])) { ?>
    <form method="post" action="logonProcess.php">
    <div>Username <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Username"></div>
    <div>Password <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password"></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Logon"></div>
    </form>
<?php } else { }?>



<?php if (isset($_SESSION['uName'])) { 
    $username = $_SESSION['uName'];     
    echo "<p>Welcome $username</p>\n";
?>
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>

<?php } else { }?>
```

Logout.php

```
<?php
unset($_SESSION['user']);
session_destroy(); // Destroying All Sessions
header("Location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at the manual about the referrer, http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php. It isn't always set. Should check and have a default if not `Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.`.

Comment: Have you tried [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3512570/3583859) Accepted Answer

Comment: Why are you unsetting a different session variable than the one you set?

Comment: @Vijay Thanks that work

Comment: @Barmar thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

Try starting session first:

Logout.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  unset($_SESSION['uName']);
  session_destroy(); // Destroying All Sessions
  header("Location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
?>
```

source from: http://www.hackingwithphp.com/10/3/5/ending-a-session

Comment: Winner winner, you can't access a session or even unset it without starting the session.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your logout file:

```
unset($_SESSION['uName']);
```

Answer (score 1):

All your scripts that use sessions need to use the same `session.save_path` setting. Since you set that in `index.php`, you also need to set it in `logout.php`. Otherwise, `logout.php` won't be able to access the session data.